# App auto renewals in app subscriptions

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-subscription

Is there a way to get the application renewals for in app subscription.

I have in app subscription inside my app i wan't to count the number that the user renew the in app subscriptions (Purchase).

(In app subscription history inside application).

Answer (score 0):

You should use `mkstorekit`

Check this link

http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/mkstorekit-4-0-supporting-auto-renewable-subscriptions/

Hope it helps.

Comment: what is issue doesn't it helped you?